# I2S, How to avoid FIFO underrun? can't understand the reference material

Tags: c++, buffer, fifo, mbed

I am trying to transmit via I2S from my K64F. I do not full understand this section of the reference material:

```
If the Transmit FIFO is empty, the TDR [Transmit Data Register] must be 
written at least three bit clocks before the start of the next unmasked
word to avoid a FIFO underrun.
```

Whenever I try to send data I notice the FIFO Error Flag (which indicates if underrun has occurred) is set, however I am not sure how to accomplish what it is described above.

[Reference Manual](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/K64P144M120SF5RM.pdf) (page 1753)

Comment: I don;t know that microcontroller or the datasheet very well, but a cursory glance shows there's a FIFORequestFlag and interrupt, have you polled or received an interrupt from that and put more data into the Tx FIFO?

Comment: Yes the interrupt calls and I can add more data, however even if I write 1 to reset the FIFO Error Flag at the same time, it is reset right away, indicating FIFO underrun.

Comment: Are you filling the FIFO or just adding one word to it?

Comment: Adding 8 words. Checking and resetting the flags each time.